# multi-level dropdown bootstrap 3 navwalker

Tags: php, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I trying to get a multi-level dropdown menu done in Bootsrap 3 and navwalker in Wordpress and need some assistent with it. I don't even know if it is possible because, if I read the manual of navwalker, it says it only supports one child for the dropdown menu because of the mobile first approach.

Despite of that, i think i should be possible by checking this website: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/issues/26

Unfortunatly when I edit line 118, in my case, the dropdown isn't working and the caret on my top nav-item is gone.

I think more people have truggled with this, so there must be an option to get this working.

Hope somebody can help me with this.

Thanks in advanced!

Roland

Answer (score 1):

This issue my point you in the right direction for adding support to the walker class https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/issues/32

You will also need to add some CSS for anything pas the first submenu as Bootstrap 3 doesn't natively support it.

If you really do need multi level dropdowns you can always use Bootstrap 2.3.2 which has support for multi level dropdowns built in. You can find my walker for Bootstrap 2.3.2 here: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/tree/For-Bootstrap-2.3.2

-Edward